# darknet YOLOv3 GPU使用時のmakeについて

Tags: ubuntu, 深層学習, gpu

環境は
Ubuntu 16.04 
CUDA 9.1
Opencv 3.3.0

YOLOv3をGPUを使って利用しようと考えたのですが、makeでエラーが出ます。
以下行ったこと

```sh
git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet
cd darknet
vim Makefile #GPU=1, OPENCV=1に変更
make
```

エラー内容

```sh
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda-9.1/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h:48,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h:45,
                 from include/darknet.h:25,
                 from ./src/utils.h:5,
                 from ./src/gemm.c:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:485:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
 namespace cv {
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'obj/gemm.o' failed
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 1
```

Comment: OpenCV のバージョンを追記してくださいませんか？　Darknet の https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/485 などの issue によると、OpenCV 3.4.1 の C API にはバグがあり、これにひっかかっている場合同様のエラーが出るようです。

Comment: Docker 上の Ubuntu 16.04.3 に OpenCV 3.3.0, CUDA 9.1 をインストールして darknet をビルドしてみたのですが、エラーが出ずコンパイルが通ってしまいました。エラーメッセージを見るに OpenCV 関係のエラーだとは思うのですが、OpenCV のインストール周りに何かありませんでしょうか。

Comment: OpenCVに問題があると思い、バージョン3.4.0でビルドし直しました。それでも上記とすこし違った下記のエラーが出てしまいました。`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
make: *** [darknet] Error 1`

Comment: そのエラーは先程のものとはだいぶ違うものに見えますね……。バージョンが変わってしまい一旦整理したいので、別の質問として再度ご投稿頂けませんか？

Answer (score 1):

結論としてOpencv 3.4.0でもdarknetの`make`が実行できました。
様々なことを試していたためどれが本当に効いたのかわかりませんが、私が行ったことを記載しておきます。
darknetのMakefileでまず`OPENCV=1`にして他を0にして`make`する。
`make`が実行できた後に`make clean`を行う。
最後にdarknetのMakefileで`OPENCV=1, GPU=1`にして`make`すると実行できました。

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 関係のエラーです。OpenCV の名前空間自体が見つけられていないので、おそらく OpenCV が上手く認識されていないのだと思います。OpenCV まわりの環境設定を見直してください。

また、今回のご質問とはバージョンが違いますが、OpenCV 3.4.1 では OpenCV 自体にバグがありビルドできません。修正されるのを待つか、ダウングレードしてください([参考](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/485))。なお今回のご質問と同じバージョンである OpenCV 3.3.0 の場合、こちらの環境ではビルドに成功しています。